When copying and pasting data using Ag Grid, the 'processCellFromClipboard' callback is not behaving the way it should
I am troubleshooting an issue we are having with the Ag Grid, specifically entire row copy and paste of data (i.e. duplicating data). We are copying using the built-in functionality of the Ag Grid, but when pasting the data into a new row, the behavior is not always consistent:

If I highlight the first cell in the new row (pinned to the top), and then press Ctrl+V, the data is copied fine.
If I click any other cell in the new row, then the data in the 'params' argument of the  'processCellFromClipboard' callback is not in the same order. The 'params.value' value and the column as defined in the 'params.column' property, do not match up at all. It appears as thought the 'params.value' value is returning values in the order of the layout of the grid, but the 'params.column' field is starting from the cell you highlighted, and then moving in some random fashion.

Am I perhaps missing something here in the implementation of the 'Paste' functionality?
Take note that the grid we are using is not a fixed layout (i.e. users can change the layout of the column and pinned columns) as needed per user.
Trying to use 'sendToClipboard', but it seems that callback is not being fired.
I tried moving the logic around, but same result.
We are using v29.2.0 of Ag Grid currently.
